# Is there an Arcgis esri commonjs version?

Tags: javascript, webpack, browserify, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am working with geolocation with Arcgis Esri.

After doing some research I was wondering if there is any versión in npm to work with commonjs, I see every time I work the examples that there is a call to arcgis modules by using AMD notation.

Comment: I would not expect the ArcGIS API to have a release in a commonjs format, nor be distributed via npm any time soon. If you want use it in a browser, but would like to use a module bundler like webpack instead of the Dojo build system for your application, there are a few established workarounds. I explain and compare those in [this blog post](http://tomwayson.com/2016/11/27/using-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-in-applications-built-with-webpack/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the ArcGIS API for JavaScript is really designed for front end coding it makes more sense that it implements AMD rather than commonjs.

This is the closest you are going to get to integrating it with other build tools for right now.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_bower_custom_builds.html#build-requirejs

Esri is making slow but steady progress making their API compatible with modern dev tools. Many of the APIs limitations are inherited from Dojo.

Comment: I see your point :) thanks for the quick answer, do you now if there is any implementation that works by mixing commonjs / amd.

I did some research looking at web pack http://simonsmith.io/commonjs-and-amd-coexisting-with-webpack/ . I would like to keep on using commonjs or es2015 import statements with some transformation/loader and in the other hand keep on using arcgis with AMD.

Comment: I have tried many hacks to get the the Dojo loader to work with other loaders and have to yet to make it work. Sorry I can't be of more help.